# How to fomat $scope.datenow inside controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a hard time formatting my $scope.date now, I want to display it like this format: Jan 1, 2014 but it always gives me that standard time with UTC, any help please?

How can I format my `$scope.date = new Date();` inside my contoller, I don't need it to display in my html

Comment: if you dont want to display in html so you can formate as javascript and do what ever you want.

Comment: you can find lot of answer date formate using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Inject the $filter into the controller,

```
app.controller('MyController',['$scope','$filter',function( $scope,$filter){ 

  var today = new Date();
  $scope.date= $filter('date')(today,'mediumDate');
  //or you can also use like this
  $scope.anotherDate= $filter('date')(today,'MMM dd, yyyy');

})];
```

now you can use `$scope.date` or `$scope.anotherDate`, will give you a date in `Apr 24, 2019` format